# Why does the constructor of a superclass automatically execute when i create a subclass in main()?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I don't really use `super()` anywhere but still the superclass' constructor is called. Why is it so?

```java
class SuperDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B subClass = new B();
        subClass.showbiz();
    }
}

class A{
    int i;
    A(){
        i = 10;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    
    void showbiz(){
        System.out.println("i in subclass " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is part of the language.  If you don't call a `super` explicitly the compiler calls the no-arg version.  Always.

Comment: It's implicit. It must be called. As a convenience, the compiler allows you to not call it explicitly, but it's called whether or not you write it.

Comment: If you have a subclass of `A`, then instances of that subclass *are* instances of `A`, so they have to be constructed in accordance with `A`'s rules (plus possibly some additional rules imposed by the subclass). It never makes sense to construct an instance of `A` without calling its constructor. If you find yourself in a situation where that makes sense to do, then you shouldn't be using inheritance in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the language works. If you don't explicitly call the superclass' constructor using `super`, the default constructor of the superclass will be called implicitly.